# Dimensions Calculated w/ Javascript to Draw Div Boxes is Off

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to make a little tool that will draw and overlap boxes of different sizes. Users will input their dimensions as feet and I will multiply all dimensions by 50px to get the correct aspect ratio for each box. However, the aspect is not being maintained for each box. It seems the outer box (green grass, from width/length form inputs) has some sort of padding that is messing up its ratio to the chosen box size from the dropdown (pink flowers).

What should be happening is that if I enter 4 and 6 in the width/height boxes, respectively, and I select 4x6 from the dropdown, those boxes should be the exact same size and I should only see the pink flowers. However, the outer green box is larger.

```js
function draw() {
    var width = document.getElementById("wid").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("hgt").value;
    var box = document.getElementById("boxSize").value;
    //updateForm(width, height, box);
    
    switch(box) {
        case 'three-two':
            document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].style.width = 3 * 50;
            document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].style.height = 2 * 50;
            break;
        case 'four-six':
            document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].style.width = 4 * 50;
            document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].style.height = 6 * 50;
            break;
        case 'five-seven':
            document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].style.width = 7 * 50;
            document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].style.height = 5 * 50;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("outer")[0].style.height = height * 50;
    document.getElementsByClassName("outer")[0].style.width = width * 50;
}
```

```css
input[type=number], select{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
div.container {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #417da6;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;     
 }
.inner-box {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="form-container">
  <form id="areaform">
    <label for="wid">Width:</label>
    <input id="wid" type="number">
    <label for="hgt">Length:</label>
    <input id="hgt" type="number">
    <label for="boxSize">Rug Size</label>
    <select id="boxSize" Box="boxSize">
      <option value="three-two">3x2</option>
      <option value="four-six">4x6</option>
      <option value="five-seven">5x7</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="draw()" type="button">Draw Boxes</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="box-container">
    <div class="inner-box">
  <div class="outer" style="display: flex;
  justify-content: center; align-items: center; background-image: url('http://ritenourequipment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/grass.jpg');  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);margin:50px;">
        <div class="inner" style="z-index: 100;   background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1437275537121-331a0457c8d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80') no-repeat center;-webkit-background-size: contain;moz-background-size: contain;o-background-size: contain;background-size: contain;"></div>
  </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong? I'm sure it's staring me in the face!

It appears to not be showing my boxes drawing in the code snippet, not sure what is going on there. It works on my browsers.

**Edited. I'm an idiot. The pictures are screwing up the sizes. I guess I can add edits to fill the div with an image I can make in the correct ratio/size for each.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be a CSS issue rather than JS - you have 50px padding in the style atribute for your outer Div